# Probability of 4 people out of 10 not being a certain nationality (Poisson)

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The question follows a Poisson Distribution, where the average number of people booking a trip (λ) is 7 , 3 and 2 if they are north american, european or another nationality respectivelly.

And what I have to do is to say what is the probability of out of 10 chosen people, 4 not being either european or north american.

And here's what I tried to do: used the Poisson formula with λ=2 and x=4 (representing the 4 people that can't be european or north american) and then I used the Poisson formula again but now using λ=12 and x=6 ( representing the other 6 people that can be any nationality) and then did the sum of both. But I couldn't reach the right answer.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, or if I'm going with a wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The conditional distribution of the number of "other," given that $10$ people booked, is binomial, $n=10$, $p=\frac{2}{7+3+2}$.

Comment: Oh I see, the only thing I'm not quite understanding is why the probability of success is 2/(7+3+2) . In the Binomial Distribution λ=np right? So if we got for example: 7 as the λ for north american people, we got np=7 (=) p= 0.7 the same goes for the λ=3, where we get p=0.3. then by multiplying both we get 0.7*0.3=0.21. Am I thinking wrong? Or perhaps complicating things?

Comment: The result is usually stated for two Poisson, but that is no problem, since the number of European plus North American is Poisson parameter $7+3$. The general result, which has been proved a few times on MSE, is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X+Y=k$ is binomial with parameters $n=k$, $p=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$.  Here we take $X$ the number of "other" and $Y$ the number of European plus North American.

Comment: Ah i get it now. Thank you for the brief explanation!!!

Comment: You are welcome.